# Uploading 3D Buildings with Textures to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, arcscene, 3d-model, sketchup, extrude

I'm doing a small project where I want to create 3D buildings from building footprints. I have acquired the heights of each building and have extruded them in ArcScene. Then I use Layer 3D to feature class to create a multi patch then exported it to COLLADA using the tool multi patch to COLLADA.

Then I took into SketchUp and have colorized the buildings using its photos taken using a camera. Now I want to use some software or something open source to view my buildings. I was told ArcGIS online can do that. I was searching and I couldn't find any option where I can import the texture COLLADA. There were only options like CSV, zip files.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about doing it directly from ArcMap. I have however seen a link describing the process using ArcGIS Pro.

http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/use/get-started-scenes.htm

From reading some of the info in this link, you will need to create a scene and then import your Collada files into it.

In ArcGIS Pro there is a tool called: `Import 3D Files`m which lets you preserve the text of a multipatch. One of the file formats accepted is *.dae or Collada.

You can then follow the steps to set the scene up and then publish.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to publish your data from Pro to ArcGIS Online or upload a zipped gdb which contains your multipatch data to publish the scene layer which will display the 3D buildings in the web scene.  https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/publish-scenes.htm

One of the things not mentioned on the doc page is how you can publish scene layers to ArcGIS Online with one click from ArcGIS Pro 2.1 which you can check out here: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/sharing/overview/web-scene-layer.htm